# Spring CriteriaBuilder query JSONArray data

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have used a table for storing JSON data. For a specific client I create records for 12 months and store the data of the 12 months in JSONArray format. In that way I create one row per client.

[image]

The `approved` field can be true, false or null. What I need to do is, check whether the `approved` value is true and that the `data` is not null. I tried to search for queries JSON data but couldn't find solution.

```
    CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<ClientData> clientQuery = cb.createQuery(ClientData.class);

    Root<ClientData> clientMaster = clientQuery.from(ClientData.class);
    ..
    ..
    ..
    predicates.add(cb.isTrue(cb.function("json_contains", Boolean.class,
            clientMaster.get("Data"), cb.literal("approved"))));
    predicates.add(cb.isNotNull(cb.function("json_contains", Double.class,
            clientMaster.get("Data"), cb.literal("data"))));
```

But this gave me error:-
`com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Invalid JSON text in argument 2 to function json_contains: "Invalid value." at position 1.`

I'm using MySQL version 5.7.31. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

everything is fine except pass value as following

```
String json = new ObjectMapper().writeValueasString({"approved":true,"data":null});

cb.literal(json) // instead of cb.literal("data"),cb.literal("approved")
```

Answer (score -1):

try this way

```
if(!CommonUtils.checkIsNullOrEmpty(filterDto.getProduct()) ) {
            String a=(String.join(",",filterDto.getProduct()));
            predicates.add(cb.isTrue(cb.function("json_contains", Boolean.class,
                    userRoot.get("product"), cb.literal("\"" + a + "\""))));
           // predicates.add(userRoot.get("product").in(a));
        }
```

Comment: Thank you... But I got the reason for the error. The `data` field here can have empty value and empty is not a Double and also empty is not null.